# How to add a page before devise registration - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise for registration for members for my app. The members area will be a paid subscription service so I want to have a choose a plan page before they actually register.

Basically the same process that 37signals use for signups on basecamphq when you click plans and pricing.

http://basecamphq.com/

I have setup devise with:

members/login, members/logout, members/register

I'm guessing I can create a members controller to override devise registrations controller and add a before filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to override the Devise registrations controller but not to add a before_filter.  First you'll need a controller and view (and model) for the Plans.  Once they choose a Plan, that'll send the user to the register page.  Then in your overridden registration controller you'll create the user and associate the new user w/ the plan they chose.